# How do I mount an encrypted /home directory on another Ubuntu machine?

Tags: 12.04, usb-drive, encryption, ecryptfs, decryption

I've done something a bit, well, strange. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 directly onto a USB thumb stick, encrypting the `/home` directory as given the option during the install. The filesystem is btrfs, I believe.

I've now stuck this into my computer running Ubuntu, and I'd like to copy a file onto the USB stick. How can I go about mounting the encrypted home directory so I can copy files to it?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**NB:** *This* answer is correct, but [another - newer and faster - way](https://askubuntu.com/a/743110) exists requiring only a single step with `ecryptfs-recover-private`. Make sure to check all answers below.

---

To get access to the data on your stick and to copy files onto it you need to mount the eCryptfs. This involves several steps:

First you should insert your stick. If Ubuntu doesn't mount it automatically (It usually does.), you should mount it.

Now you should find a directory called `.Private`. If you did a default installation, this directory should sit in `/media/DISK/home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME/.Private`. In this example `DISK` is the directory where your stick is mounted and `USERNAME` is the name of the user you entered at installation. If you can't find it yourself open a terminal and enter

```
sudo find /media -type d -name .Private
```

I assume in the following steps that the directory is in `/media/DISK/home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME/.Private`.

You need the *mount password*. This is different from your login pasword. Enter the following command into a terminal:

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /media/DISK/home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

You have to enter the login password from the installation of your USB-Ubuntu (*not* your usual password). The command outputs a passphrase. Write this down or copy it into a file.

The password enables you to unlock the directory. You need to do it in two steps:

```
> sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek
Inserted auth tok with sig [123456789abcdef0] into the user session keyring
> sudo mount -t ecryptfs /media/DISK/home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME/.Private /media/myUSB
```

The first command adds your passphrase to the kernel keyring and the second tries to mount your `.Private` to the directory `/media/myUSB`. If the latte doesn't exist, you have to create it first:

```
sudo mkdir /media/myUSB
```

The `mount` command will ask again for the **login password**. Next it will ask for a bunch of stuff.

- Accept the default cipher and key size values (`aes` and `16`).
- Type `n` for plaintext passthrough.
- Type `y` for filename encryption.
- The last thing is the FileName Encryption Key (FNEK). Look at the output of the `ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek` command you just typed. There are two lines starting with `Inserted auth tok …`. Insert the value in square brackets of the second output (`123456789abcdef0`).

Now you can access the files in `/media/myUSB` and can copy from and to the directory or subdirectories.

A large part of my description is from "[Live CD method of opening a encrypted home directory](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Live_CD_method_of_opening_a_encrypted_home_directory)".

Comment: Thanks.  There were three things that caught me that might help others: 1) I needed `sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek`, note the *sudo* 2) `ecryptfs-add-passphrase` wants the unwrapped hex phrase but the `mount` takes the "login" passphrase 3) I needed to redo `ecryptfs-add-passphrase` after an umount

Comment: Thanks - this is  wonderful! Solved also my problem :)

Is there way to modify the mount command so that it would also retain the original user (uid) and group?

Answer (score 71):

You can use `ecryptfs-recover-private`.

```
ecryptfs-recover-private /media/<UUID>/home/.ecryptfs/<USERNAME>/.Private
```

It will promt for the mount password, unlock the wrapped-passphrase and mount the directory in read only mode under `/tmp/` with just single command. Use the flag `--rw` to mount the encrypted filesystem as read and write.

Note that as mentioned in the comments, you may need to run and exit `ecryptfs-manager` first for this to work.

You can check the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ecryptfs-recover-private.1.html) for more information.

Comment: Not sure why this is not accepted answer. It's A LOT faster.

Comment: @Kai Because this answer came three years later...

Comment: Although this questions is tagged 12.04, it works for 17.04.

Comment: However, when I run the command it insists that I run it as `root`

Comment: how do i make it permanent? so after each login it automatically mounts the encrypted disk, considering both: 1. the login pass is the same as the pass used for the disk 2. the passes are different ?

Comment: the flag is `--rw` with double dash. in case you get a mount(2) error, run the `sudo ecryptfs-manager` first and immediately exit (4). then repeat the above mount comand

Comment: My experience was that the solution is to attempt the instructions in *both* answers -- this one didn't seem to work by itself.  Maybe it is necessary to do the `sudo ecryptfs-add-passphrase --fnek` step from the other top answer.  Only then did this work for me.

Comment: Ha Ha.  Never mind my previous suggestion.  Better to do what *ulkas* said:  run `sudo ecryptfs-manager`and select `4. Exit` without doing anything else.  This has the surprising side-effect of making things work.

Comment: The `sudo ecryptfs-manager` saved my life! Kudos to @ulkas - this comment should be in the answer!

Comment: For me, the secret to this working is that I *MUST* specify the `/home/.ecryptfs/<USERNAME>/.Private` directory manually. ie: use `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private /home/.ecryptfs/<USERNAME>/.Private` instead of just `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private`. If I just do the latter (which *should* also work, but doesn't), I get the following "Permission denied" error: `find: ‘/run/user/1001/gvfs’: Permission denied`. This seems to be a bug in the `ecryptfs-recover-private` bash script which uses the `find` command internally, and I don't understand why using `sudo` doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 7):

I had similar problem and ended here. 
I was migrating my system to another hard drive and have the same user  with encrypted home on both old and new system.

I tried

```
ecryptfs-recover-private /media/old_disk/home/my_name/.Private
```

but that directory was in fact symbolic link to

```
/home/.ecryptfs/my_name/.Private/
```

The target directory existed, but pointed to .Private  on my **new disk**.

Correct command should be:

> ecryptfs-recover-private
>   /media/old_disk/home/.ecryptfs/my_name/.Private

maybe ecryptfs-recover-private should display warning if it detects this pattern. It looks like common mistake.

Comment: Oh, man.. thanks! I've spent sooo much time on this. Then thought I had it, only to realize, that it was indeed mounting my *new disk*... Thanks, this worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 1):

The passphrase unwrap did not work. I needed to execute:

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase /media/DISK/home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

Comment: The accepted answer has been fixed to reflect this now.