# How do I get gksu nautilus to work so I can access my encrypted hardrive from a live usb?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, home-directory, plymouth

So I running Ubuntu on my computer, I downloaded a load of stuff, turned it off and now when I turn it on it gets stuck on the splash screen.

I've make a live USB running Ubuntu to try and get my stuff off it, but I can't seem to access my stuff in the home folder of my Hard Drive. It keeps saying:

```
"This location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of “doodle”."
```

It turns out my hard-drive is encrypted.

I've managed to mount the encrypted directory in my /tmp directory.

But I am unable to use gksu Nautilus to view and copy them as when I try and install it I get the message: "E: Unable to locate package nautilus-gksu"

Comment: follow [How do I mount an encrypted /home directory on another Ubuntu machine?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/238047/how-do-i-mount-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-another-ubuntu-machine) or this thread [How to Recover an Encrypted Home Directory on Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I mount an encrypted /home directory on another Ubuntu machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238047/how-do-i-mount-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-another-ubuntu-machine)