# Ubuntu 16.04 importing all files to 16.04.1 system ??? Help save my files!

Tags: 16.04, files, security

So I screwed up not looking deeper into updating 14.04 to 16.04 and simply let the upgrade happen and then encountered the dreaded black screen. Somehow I stupidly managed to get to the point while trying to fix things to where Ubuntu would not boot up and all I got was a black screen with the blinking monitor light or, alternatively, there would be the screen that says something like "no boot disc detected or broken".

Eventually, I discovered how to reconfigure 16.04.1 so I could run it without the black screen crap out and now I have 16.04.1 running on "try out" and still have my "998 gb file/drive" showing on the Ubuntu home screen. Encrypted. Of course I "unencrypted" it with the code, but that wasn't enough...

Though I have freed it because I of course have the encryption code, I cannot not view all (root) because I do not "own" my own files and cannot log in as the official user or whatever. Though I obviously have the encryption password and the user password.

Also, when examining the "998 gb file/drive" there is no material in the "boot" file. Somehow it is gone.

Boot repair disc was a waste of time so far. It obviously didn't repair anything.

What do I do?

I am at a stalemate. I still have my over 200 gb of very important stuff. It is still there. However, when I try and simply install Ubuntu 1604.1 there is no operating system showing in effect (!) and it threatens to overwrite the whole disc wiping everything out. I can't save the saved material to an external hard drive -- it won't let me. So now what?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would strongly recommend to boot with a Linux live system and do a image backup (maybe with dd on a extra external drive). All test/tries for recovery should be done afterwards. 
Second I would 
If possible: create a snap from you backup-data and make tries to repair/changes on the copy and leave the original data as it is as soon you have a solution. Sorry for not providing you a direct help to recover you data right now.
After the backup: did you tried the steps described here: [How do I mount an encrypted /home directory on another Ubuntu machine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238047/how-do-i-mount-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-another-ubuntu-machine) 
?
If so could you please proved a detailed report what you did and the output of the used commands ?

Comment: I already did a an Ubuntu 14.04 system reinstall after finally managing to get to recovery mode and saving all my important files. The problem was with 16.04 which, unannounced, doesn't work with the radeon card on my system. I would have saved me a lot of frustration had I known before. I will make sure to read all notes before any more upgrades and search these forums.