# 14.04 ->16.04.1 upgrade aftermath --- solution possible?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, upgrade

## Post 14.04->16.04.1 upgrade, Grub2 is lost and Ubuntu doesn't load.

I've tried to fix myself, using advice I found in different Ubuntu forums;
unfortunately, it seems like I worsened the case...

I ran Boot Repair several times, but this tool couldn't solve the problem.
Here is what Boot Repair found: http://paste2.org/jnvVp1pa

My system is a Vaio S series machine,
Dual boot with Windows 7

Any help to rescue is highly appreciated!

Comment: **Back up your data.**  If you can still access your data from livecd, back it up.  Save yourself a massive headache if you still can.

Comment: I thought about that. However, stupid enough I encrypted the folder with relevant data... is there a way to access encrypted content, via livecd, for backup?

Comment: Boot from a live CD. Then you can copy all your data. Also, once in the live distro, try installing grub to /dev/sda.

Comment: @AndroidDev, even if the folder is encrypted?

Comment: @anonymous2 - http://www.howtogeek.com/116297/how-to-recover-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @anonymous2 - http://askubuntu.com/questions/238047/how-do-i-mount-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-another-ubuntu-machine