# Decrypting Home Folder from another Partition

Tags: home-directory, ecryptfs

I have two Ubuntu (16.04) installations on my computer and my main one broke down recently probably due to me fiddling with stuff. On the partition it seems that the home folder is encrypted. (Folder names in gibberish under `/.../partition/home/.ecryptfs/USERNAME/.Private`)

I learned from [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/250384/583184) the steps to get the passphrase, adding the passphrase and mounting the decrypted folder (i assume) to this directory I created `/media/myHome`.

Sadly the mounted filesystem is just as jumbled (if not identical) to the encrypted one. I am pretty sure I made one or two own choices when I set up the encryption process and this is probably what keeps me from successfully decrypting it. (Maybe changed the default algorithm or size)

Is there a way to find out how I have to decrypt it specifically?
And why is it suggested in the post that I use the second token (outputted by `ecryptfs-add-passphrase` ) even tho it defaults me to using the first?
Do I have to redo `ecryptfs-add-passphrase` after every umount? Should I try all options with both tokens?

### Update

I tried all 96 available combinations (tokens,ciphers,blocksizes,options) and the folder still turns out in garbled names. (ECRYPTFS_FNEK_ENCRYPTED.FWacp...) It tells me when I type in the wrong passphrase, so that can't be it (right?). **Please Help**