# ecrypted home partition .Private folder missing

Tags: encryption

I have ubuntu installed on a Dell laptop. It was in sleep mode (lid closed) and with low battery charge. When I open it the login screen appear and the laptop turned of (with no power).

After I plug it in and power it on I could not login... looking in forum I found some cases so I block auto mount in `fstab`, restarted the SO, login from terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> +<kbd>F1</kbd>) and run

```
e2fsck -yc /dev/sda2
```

75/0/0 erros founded and "fixed".

Now, when I mount the sda2 partition (`sudo mount /dev/sda2 /home`) I see Access-Your-Private-Data.desktop and README.txt like spected but the .Private shortcut that points to /home/.ecryptfs/username/.Private is broken... there is no /home/.ecryptfs folder...

`df -h` show that only 7Gb of 800Gb is free... so my files is there!

and the lost+found folder is full of files and folders named with #somenumber

the `ecryptfs-recover-private` says:

```
find: ‘/run/user/112/gvfs’: Permission denied
```

and find nothing...

any sugestions?

**EDITED:**

Thanks guys for the quick return. So... I created another user using only the sda1 partition and the automount still disabled in `/etc/fstab`

```
UUID=cf40cc55-18f3-4a20-a5ab-901522d6d383   /   ext4    errors=remount-ro   0       1
#UUID=6ef2647e-1847-4e0e-9a2a-c95ff78a89e4  /home   ext4    defaults        0       2
#/swapfile                      none    swap    sw      0   0
```

...now I can login with the new user:

**What is weird**

I have face this problem before, and recover worked well using `ecryptfs-recover-private` command like metioned by Seppo Erviälä [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/238047/how-do-i-mount-an-encrypted-home-directory-on-another-ubuntu-machine) , but now I see that the `.Private` shortcut points to nothing...

I logged in with the new user and mounted the partition (just clcking in taskbar shortcut). Now sda2 is mounted in `/media/bocapio/6ef2647e-1847-4e0e-9a2a-c95ff78a89e4`

listing content of this folder

> ls -lah

```
drwxr-xr-x    8 root    root  4,0K Abr 27 18:53 .
drwxr-x---+   3 root    root  4,0K Abr 28 18:24 ..
drwx------  164 root    root   16K Set  3  2014 lost+found
dr-x------    2 lucas   lucas 4,0K Abr 25 18:00 lucas
```

but there is no .Private folder! 
`sudo find /media -type d -name .Private` returns nothig!
`sudo find /media -type d -name .ecryptfs` returns nothing!

I'm afraid that the .Private folder was moved to lost+found folder...

sorry for the first poor explanation...